# In Android Studio, why is the output of Gradle console always empty?

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio 2.2.3, the output of Gradle console is always empty no matter what task I triggered. Is it deprecated?

[image]

Comment: This will help. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html

Comment: I know how to run Gradle task from CLI. I am just curious why this "Gradle Console" is empty.  What is the purpose of this console?

Answer (score 1):

> Build Your App from the Command Line In this document About build
>   types Build a debug APK Build a release APK Run your app on the
>   emulator Run your app on a device You can execute all the build tasks
>   available to your Android project using the Gradle wrapper command
>   line tool. It's available as a batch file for Windows (gradlew.bat)
>   and a shell script for Linux and Mac (gradlew.sh), and it's accessible
>   from the root of each project you create with Android Studio.
>
> To run a task with the wrapper, use one of the following commands:
>
> On Windows: `gradlew task-name`
>   On Mac or Linux: `./gradlew task-name` To
>   see a list of all available build tasks for your project, execute
>   tasks:
>   `gradlew tasks`

Read More at  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline.html

And

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html

Comment: This saved me! Turns out I needed to do a "rollback". No amount of undoing would have fixed this problem. I can't believe that the build progress is shown in the Gradle Console by default. Or at a minimum, it should be accessible from the Run menu. But, to simply fail with no other way to fine out why is rude.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that Gradle console is used for build action like "Make Project" in menu bar: 
[image]

If you run the task from Gradle panel, the output will not be shown on Gradle console.

[image]